# Copy file from JFileChooser to new directory

Tags: java, swing, file-io, directory

Ok, I'm not really sure why this doesn't work but I am trying to use JFileChooser to select a source file (C, C++, Java) then copy it into the workspace of my project. When I run it it selects the file I choose fine, it recognizes my workspace as the destination but for some reason just does not copy the file.

```
        JButton btnSelectFile = new JButton("Select File");
    btnSelectFile.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            JFileChooser FileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("C, C++ or Java Files", "c", "cpp", "java");
            FileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            int returnValue = FileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                selectedFile = FileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                filePath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                InputStream inStream = null;
                OutputStream outStream = null;
                try{
                    File source =new File(filePath);
                    File dest =new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + selectedFile.getName());
                    inStream = new FileInputStream(source);
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                    int length;
                    while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                        outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }

                    if (inStream != null)inStream.close();
                    if (outStream != null)outStream.close();
                    System.out.println("File Copied..");
                }catch(IOException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                textArea.setText("File Loaded: " + selectedFile.getName() + "\n\n\n" + "Hit 'Run Code'");
            }
            else System.out.println("Failed to Load");
                //UnitXMLReader.ChosenFile = filePath;

        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you getting any runtime error? If yes, what?

Comment: What evidence are you using that it does not copy the file?  Eclipse, for example, doesn't necessarily update its list of files in a project just because the files in the workspace directory change; you need to 'refresh' the project after files change to ensure that file changes are known to the IDE.  If you're relying on the IDE to tell you file was copied, and you aren't refreshing the project, you may think it isn't getting copied but in fact it is.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html)? I know the files are technically inputStreams, but Files.copy provides a bit more flexibility.

Comment: I tried both Files.copy and the method above. Neither gave a runtime error. In both methods I tried neither gave any indication of error but it simply didn't create the new file. I tried the suggestion offered by @afzalex and it worked for the method above. I then converted back to the Files.copy method with the same correction for the destination path and it worked so I am now successfully using Files.copy

Comment: When you use @user, he will be notified. Use it if you want to let him see what you are writing. (I thought you are not wanting to notify this to me here. Fine if you are wanting though :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following when creating destination `File`

```
File dest =new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), selectedFile.getName());
```

instead of this

```
File dest =new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + selectedFile.getName());
```

**Explaination**
Assume that `System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns `C:\Users\Me\Workspace` and `selectedFile.getName()` returns `myfile.cpp`.
Then In your case dest is representing `C:\Users\Me\Workspacemyfile.cpp` instead of
 `C:\Users\Me\Workspace\myfile.cpp`.

Tell me if it is still not clear.

Comment: No, that makes total sense. Thank you.

Comment: You can accept Answer if you find that correct(or best). @nhoughto. Just telling you if you are unaware. This way OP will gain +2 and answerer will gain +15 reputation. This is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For File dest, instead of adding the two, try separating them by a comma.

Do a sysout for dest as the addition version and the comma version to see why there is an issue with doing it that way.

Comment: Adding a comment here because I don't have the rep yet to add it to afzalex's post...

Afzalex is correct. + doesn't include the \ between the folder and file, meaning you would have to do File dest =new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + selectedFile.getName()); to make it correct. It is easier to just do the comma.